# How to stop Maven from installing project build JAR to local repository

Tags: java, maven, maven-install

I am building a JavaFX project using NetBeans. When I build the project, Maven builds and installs the project JAR to my local repository.

I don't want to install my project to local repository, how do I stop this?

Comment: Do not call `mvn install` ? Use `mvn verify` instead?

Comment: ok how do i use it in netbeans.

Comment: In netbeans, i click the build option, it do all automatically

Comment: also, i recommend you to use maven helper plugin, it helps a lot to create differents maven goals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at [Maven default lifecycles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#a-build-lifecycle-is-made-up-of-phases), maybe mvn package is a better option

Comment: how can i use netbeans configuration for changing maven lifecycle ?